# Add reaction to existing posts or comments

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

How can we "like" or add other reactions to someone else's channel message or comment via the Graph API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update: We reached out to MS Support and received the following info: "The API to reply to a message using a POST /replies request is solemnly for issuing a reply to a message, and not to edit the status of the parent message itself. Moreover, the "update chatMessage" API which is a PATCH /messages and which is the only API to edit a parent message only supports updating the policyViolation property of a chatMessage. Essentially, there is currently no documented API / already-present API examples on how to add a reaction, making this purely unsupported."

Answer (score 1):

I've not done this myself, but it certainly looks possible. You need to reply to the message, as per https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/channel-post-messagereply?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http and notice that it has a "reactions" collection. That would be populated with a `chatMessageReaction` type, as per https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/chatmessagereaction?view=graph-rest-beta

Note of warning: `chatMessageReaction` is a beta type though, so just be aware you need to call the beta endpoint, and it has a risk to use in production code as things might change.

Comment: I have reviewed (but not tested) this endpoint. From the documentation it seems that this posts a new reply (i.e. comment). It says the "body" attribute is required, which implies a message is required. I don't see a `reactions` collections in the request, only in the response.

In the Teams GUI I can just add a reaction to an existing post or comment, without creating a new comment. That is the functionality that I'm looking for, not posting a new comment.

Comment: @restfulhead: Could you please test the endpoint suggested by Hilton and let us know..

Comment: @Rama-MSFT @hilton-giesenow Sorry for the delay. Tested a few things now and non of them were successful. Without sending a body, the error message is `Missing body content`. With sending a body and `reactions` the error message is `'reactions' cannot be set in POST`

Comment: At present we don't have any direct API for this, but could you please try to edit reactions sections in the given [example-1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/channel-post-messagereply?view=graph-rest-1.0). You can update the reactions instead of body section in the given example-1.

Comment: This is what I tried and unfortunately it does not work.