# React to a Teams message using Microsoft365R

Tags: r, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams, microsoft365r

I want to add a heart reaction to a Microsoft Teams message using the `Microsoft365R` R package.

I sent a message to a channel like this:

```
library(Microsoft365R)
library(magrittr) 

# Authenticate to Azure active directory
# This tells microsoft 365R to use the CLI app id globally
options(microsoft365r_use_cli_app_id=TRUE)

# Define a team as a variable
team1 <- list_teams()[[1]]

# Define a channel as a variable
team1_channel1 <- team1$list_channels()[[1]]

# send a message
message1 <- team1_channel1$send_message("This message was sent from R to Teams!")
```

That works and sends this message:
[image: teams_message]

**How do I react to this message from R? I want to add a heart reaction.**

When I manually react to the message, I can see that from R like this:

```
# look for updates/changes
message1$sync_fields()

# pull the reaction type of the first reaction to the message

> message1$properties$reactions[[1]]$reactionType
[1] "heart"
```

It looks like a feature to react to messages isn't directly implemented in the `Microsoft365R` package yet. So instead, I probably want to use either  `message1$do_operation()` or `message1$update()` to pass an API call to the Microsoft Graph API, but I'm not sure about the correct syntax and how the package interacts with API.

Microsoft Graph API Documentation:
 [Send message](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/chatmessage-post?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)
 [Reply to a message](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/chatmessage-post-replies?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)

Microsoft365R Documentation:
 [Github page](https://github.com/Azure/Microsoft365R)
 [CRAN package page](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=Microsoft365R)

#### Edits

As of two years ago it looks like there wasn't an API endpoint to do this, but maybe something has changed since then? [Add reaction to existing posts or comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65737835/add-reaction-to-existing-posts-or-comments)

Answer (score 2):

Currently there is no direct API available for Set a reaction.

There are beta version API's available for Set a reaction to a [single message](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/chatmessage-setreaction?view=graph-rest-beta#example-1-set-a-reaction-to-a-chat-message) or a [message reply](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/chatmessage-setreaction?view=graph-rest-beta#example-3--set-a-reaction-to-a-reply-message) in a [channel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/chatmessage-setreaction?view=graph-rest-beta#example-2-set-a-reaction-to-a-message-in-a-channel) or a chat.

APIs under the /beta version in Microsoft Graph are subject to change. Use of these APIs in production applications is not supported.